# How to use @Where annotation to join two tables using both tables(parent entity and target entity) columns?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity, where-clause

### ReferenceTable.java

public enum ReferenceTable {

DEPARTMENT("department"), CASHIER("cashier");

```
private String reference;

ReferenceTable(String reference) {
    this.reference = reference;
}

public String getReference() {
    return reference;
}
```

}

### DataPointMapping.java

@Entity

@Getter

@Setter

public class DataPointMapping implements Serializable {

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 187338677362233726L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Column(name = "pos_id")
private Long posId;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ReferenceTable reference;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "pos_id", referencedColumnName = "pos_id")
@Where(clause = "data_point_mapping.reference = ReferenceTable.DEPARTMENT.toString() AND data_point_mapping.pos_id = department_location.pos_id")
private Set<DepartmentLocation> departmentLocations = new HashSet<>();

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "pos_id", referencedColumnName = "pos_id")
@Where(clause = "data_point_mapping.reference = ReferenceTable.CASHIER.toString() AND data_point_mapping.pos_id = cashier.pos_id")
private Set<Cashier> cashiers = new HashSet<>();
```

}

### DepartmentLocation.java

@Entity

@Getter

@Setter

public class DepartmentLocation implements Serializable {

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8731083124639073364L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Column(name = "pos_id")
private Integer posId;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
private Department department;
```

}

### Department.java

@Entity

@Getter

@Setter

public class Department implements Serializable   {

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5853947958819020703L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Column(unique = true)
private String name;
```

}

### Cashier.java

@Entity

@Getter

@Setter

public class Cashier implements Serializable {

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 181978858614611403L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Column(name = "pos_id")
private Integer posId;
private String name;
```

}

Hi, above mentioned are all my used entities. I am trying to join tables on the basis of some conditions using @Where annotation like

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "pos_id", referencedColumnName = "pos_id")
@Where(clause = "data_point_mapping.reference = ReferenceTable.DEPARTMENT.toString() AND data_point_mapping.pos_id = department_location.pos_id")
private Set<DepartmentLocation> departmentLocations = new HashSet<>(); 

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "pos_id", referencedColumnName = "pos_id")
@Where(clause = "data_point_mapping.reference = ReferenceTable.CASHIER.toString() AND data_point_mapping.pos_id = cashier.pos_id")
private Set<Cashier> cashiers = new HashSet<>();

But always I am getting error like
ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "data_point_mapping"

Anyone having any idea how to resolve it?

Is there any other approach to implement it?

NOTE: is there any other way to achieve this without using @WhereJoinTable and creating another join table for using @WhereJoinTable?

Any help would be highly appreciated!
```

[@Where error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjIyd.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. make sure to format your code before you post it. Make use of the different formatting options. Please follow the blog at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: in the @Where the from table is the table of DepartmentLocation. you can not filter out records of the outer entity.